# The best way to know the size of a group of True value in a very large Python bitarray

Tags: python, loops, bitarray

I have a very large Python [bitarray](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/bitarray/) (the size is more than 100million). 
I want to know the offset for each occurrence of a group of True value and the size of each group (the number of consecutive '1'). For example: 
In a bitarray(["0001110000110"]), the first occurrence of a group of True value is in offset 3 with the size of 3 and the second occurrence is in offset 10 with the size of 2.

I tried to loop through the array and count it manually, but it seems that it is not a safe method to loop through a very large bitarray. I have seen the documentation for bitarray, but I haven't been able to find an effective way to do this from the bitarray's functionalities.

Therefore, I want to know if there is any efficient way to do this.

Comment: How many `True` values do you expect to find on average - for an array of 100 million bits, 50 million `True` values? Less? More? Maybe some sort of sparse container would be more appropriate for your use case.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for an efficient way to do that you can do it in C. This function does that and returns an array of tuples (position, length).

```
static PyObject *
bitarray_searchOnes(bitarrayobject *self)
{
    idx_t p = 0;
    idx_t s = 0;

    PyObject *list = PyList_New(0);

    while (p < self->nbits) {
        if (GETBIT(self, p) == 1) {
            s+=1;
        }
        else {
            if (s != 0) {
                PyList_Append(list, (PyTuple_Pack(2,PyLong_FromLongLong(p-s),PyLong_FromLongLong(s))));
                s=0;
            }
        }
        p++;
    }
    if (s != 0) {
        PyList_Append(list, (PyTuple_Pack(2,PyLong_FromLongLong(p-s),PyLong_FromLongLong(s))));
        s=0;
    }
    return list;
}
```

you can add it to `_bitarray.c` in the source and define it in `bitarray_methods`. and you will be having `a.searchOne()` in python.

**EDIT:** A simpler way is to iterate over the bit array in python.

```
def searchOnes(bitarray)
    s=0
    ind=0
    arr=[]
    for i in bitarray:
        if i:
            s+=1
        elif s:
            arr.append((ind-s,s))
            s=0
        ind+=1
    if(s):
        arr.append((ind-s,s))
    return arr
```

But after some benchmarks on 23,000,000 bits this method took on average about `3.6 seconds` on my intel i7 machine, while the c implementation took only `1 second`.

**EDIT:** This is how I did the benchmark:

```
from bitarray import bitarray
from timeit import timeit
from random import choice

def test_searchOnes():
    ba=bitarray(''.join(choice('01') for _ in xrange(23000000)))
    print timeit(lambda:searchOnes(ba),number=1)  # the python version
    print timeit(lambda:ba.searchOnes(),number=1) # the C version
```

And the results would be:

```
3.37723302841     # the python version
0.754848003387    # the C version
```

Comment: Can you post your benchmarking code, i.e. the way you generated 23 million bits and how you timed the runtime?

Comment: @FrerichRaabe Edited. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a pure-Python implementation (works with Python 2), maybe that works better?

```
import itertools

def frerich(a):
    groups = ((k, sum(1 for _ in g)) for k, g in itertools.groupby(a))
    offset = 0
    for k, l in groups:
        if k:
            yield (offset, l)
        offset += l
```

The idea is that instead of iterating over each bit individually, we let `itertools.groupby` and `sum` do that for us (assuming that they are very efficient) and then merely iterate the groups of consecutive elements, `yield`ing the offset and length of the `True` groups. Also, the function does not build a list based on the assumption that maybe you don't even need a list in memory. Instead, it's a generator.